# My images table has a category field. Should I have the Id or the name of the category in that field?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm not sure whether to use the Id or the name of the category. I think using the Id is the convention but I wasn't too sure so I decided to ask here.

Comment: I am presuming Id has Int datatype. It is preferred to have integer values as JOIN condition. Generally, you would have two tables. One for category - `category_id, name` and another for image with category_id in it (if it one-to-one relationship). If an image can belong to multiple categories or vice versa, you will need an intermediate lookup table

Comment: Since the image should only have 1 category I only need the 2 tables for that. I do have an intermediate tables for my tags since 1 image can have many tags. So it's better to use the category id in the images table right?

Comment: Yes - preferable to use Int values for join relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah sure you must add id(int) for joins purpose.